# Deep-links work from browser, but not from facebook app (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, deeplink

I have deeplinks set in my app. When I press on a link in facebook in Chrome - it opens the app.
However, when I click the same link from within the facebook app, it doesn't open my app.

Does facebook has some restrictions with deep links? Or perhaps there's something to be added in the intent filter?

Comment: Are you using branch.io?

Comment: Deep linking out of the native Android Facebook app is still possible (unlike iOS, where it is blocked), but we need more detail to debug this. Ideally an example of the links you are posting. Chrome uses Chrome Intents, which are a very different form of deep linking than most other apps.